# What strange magic is *this?

Tags: c++

Quick question.  I want to understand the behaviour of *this in C++.
Forgive me if this is too obvious, or is a repeat, due to search engines interpreting * as a wildcard character my searches have been somewhat less than enlightening.

I'm using someone else's code, which has a number of functions that look like so:

(Type of N is struct)

```
N N::someMethod() const {

    N n = *this;
    // do a function that modifies internal values of the struct
    n.modify();
    return n;

}
```

What happens is that it returns a modified copy of the original struct, and the original struct is unmodified.

I assume that somehow *this is making a copy, but I don't understand why/how.  Is this some magic to do with structs?  Is it the const in the function declaration?  Is there some other magic going on behind the scenes?

My understanding is that 'this' is a pointer.  I had thought that when you * a pointer, it simply dereferenced that pointer??  (So I expected n to point to the same chunk of memory as the original, but obviously it doesn't, so my intuition is borken)

Please feel free to point out the error of my ways, in detail if you like.  It's okay, I'm smart enough to grok a detailed technical discussion of what is going on under the hood, I promise!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick answers.  Thou art all princes (and princesses) amongst men.  Upboats for all!

Comment: Also, for clarity, the code is doing what it should.  If it wasn't supposed to create and return a modified copy, but was supposed to modify the original in situ, then the return type would be void, not N.  I just didn't understand the why/how of the behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*this` by itself does not make any copy, it just make type correct for copy constructor that will be called by `N n = ...`.

Comment: No, `operator =` will be used in `N n; n=*this;` . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor

Comment: Thanks for the link Alexei.  It made clear to me that what the code was doing is similar to:

    int a = 1;
    int b = a;

Here my intuition says that a and b both hold the value 1, but they are different 'instances' of 1.  It makes sense to me now.  :D

Answer (score 13):

No, this is magic from *before* the dawn of time (a thinly veiled Narnia reference). It harkens back to the C language.

Since `this` is simply a pointer to the current object, `*this` is the object itself, and the line:

```
N n = *this;
```

simply makes a copy of said object. Then, it modifies that copy and returns it.

If you wanted a copy of the *pointer* to the same object, that would be:

```
N *n = this;
```

It's no different to the following:

```
int xyzzy = 7;           // xyzzy holds 7.
int *pXyzzy = &xyzzy;    // the address of xyzzy.

int plugh = *pXyzzy;     // a *different* address, also holding 7.
int *pTwisty = pXyzzy;   // copy *address*, pXyzzy/pTwisty both point to xyzzy.
```

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo.  I wish I could mark multiple questions as the definitive and correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `this` is "pointer to N", so `*this`, the [dereference operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) applied to `this`, is an `N`. There is no copying performed in the expression `*this`. It just provides a reference to the object pointed at by `this`.

The rest is [copy initialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm), similar to

```
N n1;
N n2 = n1; // initialize n2 copying the value of n1
```

Comment: @Aubin it is a copy construction. No assignment takes place.

Answer (score 3):

```
N n = *this;
```

is known as **Copy Initialization**. It does usually create a copy.

It constructs an implicit conversion sequence by trying to convert `*this` to an object of type `N`, then *may* copy over that object into the to-initialized object, thus leading a call to copy constructor.

Comment: @Aubin: Sorry but you are incorrect and so is the other downvoter.

Comment: I'm curious. Under what circumstances does this not make a copy? I thought it would _always_ do that.

Answer (score 1):

The work is done by the copy constructor even if the sign `=` is present.

The following code show some echo of its execution:

```
#include <iostream>

class N {
public:

   N(){}

   N( const N & n ) {
      std::cout << "N( const N & n )" << std::endl;
   }

   N& operator = ( const N & n ) {
      std::cout << "N& operator = ( const N & n )" << std::endl;
      return *this;
   }

   N modify() const {
      std::cout << "modify|entry" << std::endl;
      N n2 = *this;
      std::cout << "modify|exit" << std::endl;
      return n2;
   }
};

int main() {
   N n1;
   n1.modify();
}
```

With this output:

```
modify|entry
N( const N & n )
modify|exit
N( const N & n )
```

Comment: -1 There is no `operator =` involved here.This is Initialization not Assignment! When you create and assign a value to an object it is Initialization not Assignment.

Comment: You can't decide without the code. Try it step-by-step under debugger.

Comment: There is no need to debug.This cannot be assignment in any possible way.The copy constructor may or may not be called but the `operator =` is just plainly wrong.

Comment: Both you statements are correct: `*this` does not make a copy, but the `operator=` makes copies. But in the code given in the question, the copy is made as part of a copy initialization, which means `operator=` isn't used. The copy constructor is used.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The assignment operator has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes, I apologized. Verbatim program test this behavior.

Comment: Your first sentence still claims that the copy is done by `operator=`, contradicting the output beneath it.

Comment: Yes, I have made an edit. My 'Wrong' was unclear, I hope it's better now.

Comment: The first and second sentences of the response now contradict each other, one claiming that the copy is done by `operator =`, other by the constructor. This confuses the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that "this" is a pointer. "This" is a pointer to the instance of the object you are inside of, if that makes sense.

I believe the problem is the "N n = *this" line.

You dereferenced the pointer and invoked the copy constructor. This is the line that is creating a copy.

I believe what you are looking for is something more along the lines of this:

```
N * N::someMethod() {

    this->modify();
    return this;
}
```

the -> operator is the same as writing "(*this)."

Note that I changed the method to a return a pointer, or you might just end up invoking the copy constructor again when you assign the return value of this function to something else.

Also, unless modify is also a const method (which seems unlikely, given the name), you shouldn't be able to write someMethod as a const method. (You cannot change the logical contents of an object in a const method.)

Comment: There is no "problem", the OP is looking for an explanation of how the (correct) code works. Your suggested modification would make the method destructively modify the object, and break the code.

Comment: I apologize, the OP has made no mistake. However, the code as it is given creates an object on the stack, modifies it, and then returns it as another object. This calls the copy constructor twice, and to be honest I can think of no good reason that this would be necessary. It would make more sense to just create a copy outside of a method and call modify.

Comment: The copy constructor needn't always be destructive, and sometimes there are good uses for methods that return new objects instead of modifying existing ones. For example, `N` could be immutable by nature, and the `modify` method private.

Comment: I am keeping the downvote—there is no indication whatsoever that the OP is "looking for" a modification like the one suggested in the answer. In fact, the modification as presented would be highly inadvisable because it changes `someMethod` from `const` to non-`const`, which is an incompatible interface change in the code base maintained by the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting discussion.  @user1489722: Quick question, why is it copied twice?  Is it copied again when it is returned?

Comment: Yes. In your code, the object that someMethod returns is not actually n, but a new object copy constructed from n. Otherwise, n would go out of scope once the method exits.

Comment: Ah!  The variable N is declared inside a function, so it must go on the stack.  It, and all other variables declared inside the function (unless created via new or malloc or similar heapifying (in which case it would leak unless returned)) will get blown away when the function returns.  Huh.  So something must happen to it when the function returns... But returning from a function should simply put the return value on top of the stack... is it copied/moved there?

Now you've got me wondering about the deep internal workings of C/C++ functions...

Comment: It doesn't need to be copied twice at all. Google "return value optimization".